# Several errors in the selection of important features with genetic algorithms:

Tags: python, generics, genetic-algorithm, feature-selection, keyerror

code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import target as target
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


dataset = pd.read_csv('Tehran_hies98.csv')

to_drop = ['Address', 'weight', 'WH', 'inc3', 'Income', 'exp1', 'exp4', 'exp5', 'exp6', 'exp7', 
          'exp8', 'exp11'
        , 'exp12', 'exp13', 'Income_Mis', 'exp2', 'exp3', 'exp9', 'inc2', 'inc1', 'exp14']

dataset.drop(to_drop, inplace=True, axis=1)

dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset,
                     columns=['HSize', 'SSex', 'SAge', 'SMadrak', 'SActivity', 'SMarital', 
                              'Tasarrof', 'Otagh',
                              'ZirBana'], drop_first=True)

target, feature_list = 'DV', [i for i in dataset.columns if i not in target]


def init_population(n, c):
     return np.array([[math.ceil(e) for e in pop] for pop in (np.random.rand(n, c) - 0.5)]), 
     np.zeros((2, c))-1

def single_poin_crossover(population):
       r, c, n = population.shape[0], population.shape[1], np.random.randint(1, population.shape[1])
       for i in range(0, r, 2):
             population[i], population[i + 1] = np.append(population[i][0:n], population[i + 1] 
             [n:c]), np.append(
             population[i + 1][0:n], population[i][n:c])
       return population

def flip_mutation(population):
      return population.max() - population

def random_selection(population):
   r = population.shape[0]
   new_population = population.copy()
   for i in range(r):
       new_population[i] = population[np.random.randint(0, r)]
   return new_population

def get_fitness(data, feature_list, target, population):
   fitness = []
   for i in range(population.shape[0]):
       columns = [feature_list[j] for j in range(population.shape[1]) if population[i, j] == 1]
       fitness.append(predictive_model(data[columns], data[target]))
   return fitness

def predictive_model(X, y):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)
    lr = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', max_iter=100, random_state=7)
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    return accuracy_score(y_test, lr.predict(X_test))


def genetic_algorithm(data, feature_list, target, n, max_iter):
  c = len(feature_list)

  population, memory = init_population(n, c)
  temp1 = population
  temp2 = memory
  population, memory = temp2, temp1

  fitness = get_fitness(data, feature_list, target, population)

  optimal_value = max(fitness)
  optimal_solution = population[np.where(fitness == optimal_value)][0]

  for i in range(max_iter):
      population = random_selection(population)
      population = single_poin_crossover(population)
      if np.random.rand() < 0.3:
          population = flip_mutation(population)
      temp1 = population
      temp2 = memory
      population, memory = temp2, temp1

      fitness = get_fitness(data, feature_list, target, population)

      if max(fitness) > optimal_value:
          optimal_value = max(fitness)
          optimal_solution = population[np.where(fitness == optimal_value)][0]

  return optimal_solution, optimal_value


feature_set, acc_score = genetic_algorithm(dataset, feature_list, target, 10, 1000)
feature_set = [feature_list[i] for i in range(len(feature_list)) if feature_set[i] == 1]

print('Optimal Feature Set\n', feature_set, '\nOptimal Accuracy = ', round(acc_score * 100), '%')
```

First error:
target, feature_list = 'DV', [i for i in dataset.columns if i not in target]
TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable

for code:

```
target, feature_list = 'DV', [i for i in dataset.columns if i not in target]
```

Second error:
If I delete this part of the above code:

```
 if i not in target
```

This error appears:

raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'DV'

I wrote this code and so far this problem has arisen.

If you see any other bugs, please help me fix it.

Please help me if possible or put the correct code

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you may have some variable confusion here. First off, what is `import target as target` at the top? The line giving the error should be throwing an error like `NameError: name 'target' is not defined` except that you've imported target from another module but are trying to assign it. The problem is, `target` isn't `'DV'` until after it's assigned, which it isn't because you can't assign it this way in the same line you're trying to use it. Break that line up into two lines and you may have a better result

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for doing this code?